# Unable to Take Screenshots Using Firefox Nodes

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-grid

My Selenium tests are designed to take screenshots on failure and add them to the report. The screenshots are displaying perfectly for chrome browsers, but Firefox screenshots are just white rectangles.The changelog says something about a "pass through" mode https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG which I've tried to disable, but nothing seems to be working.

Here's my docker compose file:

```
seleniumhub:
  image: selenium/hub
  ports:
    - 4444:4444

firefoxnode:
  image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
  ports:
    - 4577
  links:
    - seleniumhub:hub
  environment:
    - enablePassThrough=false
    - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=5
    - NODE_MAX_SESSION=5

chromenode:
  image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
  ports:
    - 4578
  links:
    - seleniumhub:hub
  environment:
    - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=5
    - NODE_MAX_SESSION=5
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `enablePassThrough` is a valid environment variable. The configuration is generated from https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/NodeFirefox/generate_config which only contains your `NODE_MAX_INSTANCES` and `NODE_MAX_SESSION`.

However, there is a `SE_OPTS` variable from the parent base image in the entrypoint at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/master/NodeBase/entry_point.sh#L28-L30. You can use this to set `-enablePassThrough false`. Your service definition in Docker Compose would be something like this instead:

```
firefoxnode:
  image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
  ports:
    - 4577
  links:
    - seleniumhub:hub
  environment:
    - SE_OPTS="-enablePassThrough false"
    - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=5
    - NODE_MAX_SESSION=5
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, passing it that way did not work. I got `Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed main parameter '"-enablePassThrough' but no main parameter was defined`

Comment: Hmm, that sounds like it is passing the quotes verbatim. Trying just as `- SE_OPTS=-enablePassThrough false`.

Comment: I got this Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -enablePassThrough=false

Comment: You are pulling the latest tag on all the images. Can you confirm the image ID and also add a tag for the latest `3.5.3-boron` tag? Also, the option says it is for the server. Is it possible it is for the hub only?